# How to accurately track the 75% quantile in a non-stationary timeseries?

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, quantiles, stationarity

I have a non-stationary timeseries with a mean (µ) and standard deviation (SD) which both vary  across time. The distribution of the timeseries is skewed, so the left and right sides of the distribution must be treated separately.

I am wondering what is the best way to accurately track the 25% and 75% quantile?

**What I have tried**

I have tried calculating the 25% quantile within a rolling window, then feeding these values into the forecast() package to smooth them out. I'm wondering if there is a better way of doing this, because one of the constraints is that there is not much data: I only have about 50 samples within each window, any more and the SD and mean have changed so much that they are out of date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I'd try a combination of the `splines` and `quantreg` packages.  Then you can do a `y~ns(time,df=6)` with `tau=c(0.25,0.75)`.  You'd have to tune the df=6 part subjectively of course.  Instead of the `splines` package, `quantreg` ties pretty closely to the `cobs` package that gives a few ways to optimize the amount of curvature.  I like the linear edges of a `ns()` however.

Alternatively, couldn't you do a box-cox transformation to reduce the skew and then fit some manner of ARCH model?

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The quantreg package looks amazing, I'm reading it now.

Comment: Just noticed I didn't specify those were `R` packages.  I know at least SAS has comparable functionality in `Proc Quantreg`.  You can also use the `gbm` package in R and a quantile loss function to get similar answers.